# Selecting different number of columns in a CSV file

Tags: sql, csv

**The task** is to extract data from multiple CSV files according to a criteria. The file contains a sampleId (this is the criteria) and other columns. At the end of the file there are the measurement values under 0...100 named columns (the numbers are the actual names of the columns). To make it a bit more interesting there can be variations in different CSV files, depending on the customer needs. This means the measurement data count can be 15, 25, 50 etc. but no more than 100 and no variations within one file. This data is always placed in the end of the line, so there is a set of columns before the numbers.

I'd like to have a SQL statement which can accept parameters:

```
SELECT {0} FROM {1} WHERE sampleId = {2}
```

**0** is the numbers, **1** is the CSV file name and **2** is sampleId is what we looking for. The other solution which came into my mind is to look all the columns after the last fix column. I don't know is it possible or not, just thinking out loud.

Please be descriptive, my SQL knowledge is basic. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Tag dbms used, since you'll probably need product specific functionality.

Comment: I am not using database, simply just opening the file from the location and following a OleDb example: http://forums.asp.net/t/1282715.aspx?How+to+search+for+a+value+in+a+csv+file+and+return+another+value+

Comment: You can't _not_ use a database if you are using SQL. And the possibilities to manipulate or access CSV files are highly DBMS dependent

Comment: Then sorry I don't understand jarlh's comment.

Comment: Double negations... You have to use a database if you use SQL...

Comment: OK I get that, but if you check the link you can see, they are using sql statement with a csv file.

Answer (score 0):

So finally managed to solve it. The code is in VB.NET, but the logic is quite clear.

```
 Private Function GetDataFromCSV(sampleIds As Integer()) As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of Integer)))
           Dim dataFiles() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(OutputFolder(), "*.CSV")
           Dim results As List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of Integer))) = New List(Of KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of Integer)))

          If dataFiles.Length > 0 And sampleIds.Length > 0 Then
                  For index As Integer = 0 To sampleIds.Length - 1
                       If sampleIds(index) > 0 Then
                            For Each file In dataFiles
                                 If System.IO.File.Exists(file) Then
                                      Dim currentId As String = sampleIds(index).ToString()
                                      Dim filename As String = Path.GetFileName(file)
                                      Dim strPath As String = Path.GetDirectoryName(file)

                                   Dim conn As OleDb.OleDbConnection = New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" & strPath & "; Extended Properties='text; HDR=Yes; FMT=Delimited'")

                                   Dim command As OleDb.OleDbCommand = conn.CreateCommand()
                                    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM [" & filename & "] 'WHERE Sample ID = " & currentId

                                   conn.Open()
                                   Dim reader As OleDb.OleDbDataReader = command.ExecuteReader()
                                   Dim numberOfFields = reader.FieldCount  
                                   While reader.Read()
                                            If reader("Sample ID").ToString() = currentId Then 'If found write particle data into output file
                                                 Dim particles As List(Of Integer) = New List(Of Integer)
                                                 For field As Integer = 0 To numberOfFields - 1
                                                     particles.Add(CInt(reader(field.ToString())))
                                                 Next field
                                                 results.Add(New KeyValuePair(Of String, List(Of Integer))(currentId, particles))
                                            End If
                                       End While
                                       conn.Close()
                                  End If
                             Next file
                    End If
               Next index
               Return results
          Else
               MessageBox.Show("Missing csv files or invalid sample Id(s)", "Internal error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
         End If
         End Function
```